# How do I find what TFS template was used?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We have TFS 2012, and have a lot of projects created back in version 2008 of TFS.
Is there a way of finding the name of the TFS project template that was used when creating the TFS project?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way for finding the template name from a SQL query. However, this will only list those projects that were created in TFS2012

```
USE Tfs_DefaultCollection

SELECT        tbl_projects.project_name AS [Team Project], tbl_project_properties.value AS [Process Template]
FROM            tbl_projects INNER JOIN
                         tbl_project_properties ON tbl_projects.project_id = tbl_project_properties.project_id
WHERE        (tbl_project_properties.name LIKE '%Process Template%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.
You may check the Work Item Types available in a project and infer the Process Template used, e.g. "MSF for Agile Software Development" had a "Quality of Service Requirement".

Comment: So this is not stored anywhere in the TFS database ?

Comment: Sadly no.
There is such a table, but in 2012.2 or something like that. It is populated only during project creation so migrated projects have no data.

Answer (score 1):

[TFS Team Project Manager](http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex is a free tool which will inspect all your team projects process templates (even if they're customized) and tell you which process template was most likely used to create that Team Project (and give you a % confidence in the match). You can even give it additional "source" process templates, such as your company custom process template, and it will tell you which projects were created with it.

[image]